# What is a word for ignoring or overlooking evil actions?

Tags: synonyms

Example:  The good people of Germany ____ the Holocaust.

Comment: Did you look up _ignore_ and _overlook_ in a thesaurus? If so, were none of the suggestions useful?

Comment: You could feasibly say they're ***in denial***, with the sense of *refusing to think about it*. But that might be confused with ***denying***  the Holocaust *(claiming it didn't happen),* which is one of relatively few things generally recognized as an "International" crime.

Answer (score 4):

I think

> to turn a blind eye

is what you are looking for.

> **Explanation**
>
> Turning a blind eye is an idiom describing the ignoring of undesirable information.
>
> [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turning_a_blind_eye)

Answer (score 1):

*The good people of Germany **turned a tin eye** to the Holocaust*

> *I might say that the college has turned a tin eye to my entreaties.*
>
> [muhlenberg.edu](http://muhlenberg.edu/cultural/magazine/MuhlenbergMagazineWinter2014.pdf)
>
> **have a tin ear**
>
> *informal* Be tone-deaf: (figurative) *the company has had a tin ear for hearing what customers want*
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have-a-tin-ear)